# When does the norm of the sum of $n$ vectors equal the sum of the norms of the vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, triangle-inequality

I'm trying to prove the following:
Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. For vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, $$\left\lvert\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\right\rvert = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lvert x_i \rvert,$$
if and only if for some $j$, there exist nonnegative real numbers $a_i$ such that for all $i \neq j$ we have $x_i=a_ix_j$.

I was able to prove the converse of the statement relatively easily, but I have no clue where to begin for the forward direction.

Comment: Let $x\in V$ be arbitrary and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n>0$. Then $|\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k x|=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k |x|$

Comment: @SahanManodya, this is just the following answer

Answer (score 3):

By the polygon inequality, which is a generalized triangle inequality, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|\geq \left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right|$$
with equality when $x_i$ are all a positive scalar multiples of eachother.

Comment: Do you know of any proof for the polygon inequality or if there's some place where I could find more information on it?

Comment: @JRB Search up triangle inequality. It generalizes to the polygon quite readily once you have proved triangle inequality. I think triangle inequality can be proven with cauchy schwarz

Comment: I was able to generalize the inequality by induction, but proving the condition where it becomes an equality is the part I'm stuck on currently.

Comment: @JRB To prove equality, you can go back to the equality condition of Cauchy Schwarz